# How to remove EXIF data from file uploaded to Cloud Storage via Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, exif

I am uploading files, including pictures and videos taken on phones with location data, to a Cloud Storage bucket via the Firebase Storage SDK.  How can I remove the EXIF data from these files?  It would be nice to remove them on the client side, but if it requires a Cloud Function, that's fine.

Comment: You will have to do this on the client (or your middleware backend) before the ufinal pload happens.  Cloud Storage won't modify the contents of the upload for you.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  Want to make that an answer so I can credit you with Accepted Answer?

Comment: It's not really an answer though. I'm sure you can find a library or utility to actually remove the exif data.